# Meaning of marked header values in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Can you please tell me what is the meaning of red marked header values in jmeter request headers?

Attached is the snap I am getting after running my jmx .[Header image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcLso.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `client-secret` - most probably it is connected somehow to [OAuth login flow](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/client-registration/client-id-secret/)
2. `gstin` - most probably it is connected somehow to the application you're testing, `devapi.gst.gov.in`, looking into [What is GST Number (GSTIN)?](https://www.mastersindia.co/gst-number-search-and-gstin-verification/)

   > GSTIN or Goods and Services Tax Identification Number is your unique business identity with the GoI (Government of India) that contains 15 digits alpha-numeric PAN based code.
3. `0_251` is [Java SDK 8 Update 251](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u251-relnotes-5972664.html), it is being added automatically if you don't pass [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) header containing [UserAgent String](https://deviceatlas.com/blog/list-of-user-agent-strings) of the browser of your choice via [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager)

Comment: Yes ..I am aware about this ..just wanted to know why these are marked in red??

Comment: They are marked as red because you're using ugly dark theme, if you switch to other theme from Options - > Look and Feel or by setting a [JMeter Property](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) like `jmeter.laf=CrossPlatform` it will stop being "red",  the different color is due to JMeter treats this tab as the code and tries to highlight parts of the output basing on code highlighting algorithms. You can raise an issue in [JMeter Bugzilla](https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html) or simply ignore that